# Auxiliary verbs in DisCoCat

Tags: ct.category-theory, computational-linguistics

If you have seen Coecke and Sadrzadeh's work on linguistics, or Natural Language Processing (see *"Experimenting with transitive verbs in a DisCoCat"*: [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3119), you will know they have a graphical calculus for grammar.  I am wondering about how [Auxiliary Verbs](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch09.html) work in their framework.  It seems like a natural thing for there to be a cup and cap system that connects the Auxiliary Verb to its main verb.  Can anyone explain this?